# LIST TABLES in_array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

hi i know this is probably really simple and after hours googling i have returned empty handed, I'm trying to store the LIST TABLES query into an array where i can check if a value from another array is in the resulting LIST TABLES query.

```
$SQL = new DB;

$tables = array(
"Product_Cache",
"Product_Cat",
"Product_Details",
"Product_Images",
"Site_Content",
"UserDetails",
"User_Products",
"User_Type",
"Users"
     );

$result = $SQL->doQuery("SHOW TABLES IN sellmygadgets");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

foreach ($tables as $table){
echo "Table " . $table . " Contains this many rows : " . $SQL->numRows(select_all($table)) . "<br>";
    //if(in_array($table, $row, TRUE) {

    //}
}
```

help is greatly appreciated thanks Andy

Comment: `fetch_assoc()` just returns one row of results, you need to call it in a loop to get all the rows.

Comment: is there another sqli function to fetch all rows instead ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php. You have to be using the MYSQLND driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `fetch_row()` in a loop to get all the rows of the result.

```
$result = $SQL->doQuery("SHOW TABLES IN sellmygadgets");
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    $table = $row[0];
    if (in_array($table, $tables)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help had to change the code a bit to get the in_array the other way around